# duplicate data in blade when send data

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-permission

i´m trying to show all my roles in my edit blade and with checkbox, that this checks it´s checked if this role have this permission.

my problem it´s when send data permissions and permissions to this role, all permission name it´s duplicate.

[image]

for set roles and permission i´m using laravel-permission/spatie

in my controller i have this:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $role = Role::find($id);
        $permissions = Permission::all();
        $permissionAssigned = Role::find($id)->givePermissionTo();

        return view('opciones.roles.edit', ['role' => $role, 'permissions' => $permissions, 
                                            'permissionAssigned' => $permissionAssigned["permissions"] ]);
    }
```

and in my blade i have this:

```
<h3>Permissions</h3>
                            <div class="row flex-row justify-content-center"> 
                              @foreach($permissions as $permission)
                                @foreach ($permissionAssigned as $asigned)
                                  @if($permission->name == $asigned->name)
                                    <div class="form-check p-4">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="{{ $permission->name }}" id="flexCheckDefault">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">{{ $permission->name }}</label>
                                    </div>                                                                      
                                  @endif
                                @endforeach
                                <div class="form-check p-4">
                                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="{{ $permission->name }}" id="flexCheckDefault">
                                  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">{{ $permission->name }}</label>
                                </div>
                              @endforeach                                                             
                            </div>
```

i don´t know that i´m doing wrong. I know that i have a logic problem, but i can´t solve it.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: why are you getting all permission you can get specific permission from the role $role = Role::with('permissions')->find($id); $role->permissions;

Comment: @BhargavRangani thanks for your response. I´m doing this, because i want show in my blade all permissions but select only that have it this role. And show that permissions it´s free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the `Role` with associated `Permissions` and all `Perrmissions` to compare against, from the controller.

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    $role = Role::with('permissions')->find($id);
    $permissions = Permission::all();

    return view('opciones.roles.edit', ['role' => $role]);
}
```

In the view

```php
<h3>Permissions</h3>
<div class="row flex-row justify-content-center"> 
    @foreach($permissions as $permission)
        <div class="form-check p-4">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   id="flexCheckDefault"
                   class="form-check-input"
                   name="permission[]" 
                   value="{{ $permission->name }}" 
                   @checked((old($permission->name, $role->permissions->contains('name', $permission->name)) />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">{{ $permission->name }}</label>
        </div>   
   @endforeach                                                             
</div>
```

Comment: @Donkarnahs thanks for your help, but i have same result

Comment: Have updated the answer to use `@checked` blade directive which makes the view even simpler.

Comment: @scorpions78 Does it work for you? The updated answer?